# Задание параметра vpi в настройках роутера dlink dir-651

Tags: роутер

Подскажите где задается vpi в настройках роутера dlink dir-651 желательно с помощью скриншота или хотя бы указанием пунктов меню. Очень надо.

нужен именно скриншот этого момента, а не полная настройка, потому что не был найден этот момент

Comment: так там же нет dsl , не ?

Answer (score 1):

точно нигде. этот параметр указывается в настройках adsl-модема

Answer (score 0):

> где задается vpi в настройках роутера dlink dir-651

Видимо ни где, это настройки для ADSL